# Investigating ROS Topics Simply

Tags: rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know about `rostopic list` but how can I get more info from there?

Is there a tool to investigate the info on a specific topic? Let's say I have a `rostopic` named "odometer", how can I see what values are being sent from there?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238740/investigating-ros-topics-simply/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

use rostopic echo [topic_name]

for more info. look at this :: [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics#Using_rostopic_echo)

---

Originally posted by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) with karma: 221 on 2016-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2